# Is there a Google TV API to support stereoscopic 3D video content?

Tags: google-tv

The LG Google TV has a 3D world application that supports 3D. The application automatically triggers 3D mode of the TV. What is the API for doing the same in our own application?

The ultimate goal is the playback 3D MKV files.

[Edit] Could we reverse engineer the API used by the 3D world app?

Answer (score 1):

Kristan answered this during a Google TV Developers Hangout @ 00:47.

https://developers.google.com/live/shows/7594037-6001/

The answer was: No, there is not an API so you should put in a feature request. LG can do it because they are an OEM partner and have extended access to features.